# Onchange function in Openerp

Tags: python, xml, onchange, odoo

I have a selection field in account.invoice.line named form_type.  It has three selection options:

```
1) form_a
2) form_b
3) form_c
```

There is also an integer field named *flag* in account.invoice.line.  When form_c is selected, the flag value should be set to 1; otherwise, if either form_a or form_b is selected, the flag value should be set to 0.  I wrote an *onchange* function for the above case but it's not working.  Can someone help me out?  What is wrong in my code?

```
def onchange_form_type(self, cr, uid, ids, invoice, context=None):
    val={}
    flag=0
    invoice = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line').browse(cr, uid, invoice)
    for invoice in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if invoice.form_type=="form_c":
            flag="1"
        else:
            flag="0"

    print flag
    val = { 'flag': flag, }
    return {'value': val}
```

My XML code in account.invoice.line for onchange is:

```
<field name="form_type" on_change="onchange_form_type(form_type)"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your on-change function you don't need to call the browse function of the object, because the values are not stored in the database yet. Also, you are passing the "form_type" value to the function and not the object id(as browse accepts object id).

So, below will be the on_change function, for the expected requirement:

```
def onchange_form_type(self, cr, uid, ids, form_type, context=None):

    val={}
    flag=0
    if form_type == 'form_c':
        flag="1"
    val = { 'flag': flag }
 return {'value': val}
```