# onchange function in OpenERP for values equal to default values

Tags: python, onchange, odoo

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256227/onchange-function-in-openerp) question and used it to achieve a similar goal in openerp. Hence my function:

```
def onchange_warning(self, cr, uid, ids, result, lower, upper, context=None):
    res={}
    flag = False
    if result < lower or result > upper:
        flag = True
    res = {'warning': flag}
    return {'value': res}
```

And in the view I have:

```
<field name="result" on_change="onchange_warning(result, lower, upper)"/>
```

where **result**, **lower**, and **upper** are floats, and **warning** is boolean with no default value. In the tree inside my form I have predefined values for both **lower** and **upper**, while the **result** is *null (0.00)* and set to be filled.

The function works well and does what it's supposed to. I am however facing a problem with results that are **actually equal to 0.0** and should set the flag, whereas the *onchange* function (D'Oh!) cannot be executed because the field value did not technically CHANGE from its default value of 0.00. What to do?

PS: Sorry about the horrible title, feel free to improve it :)

**EDIT:**

If anyone needs to see how the function becomes:

> ```
> def onchange_warning(self, cr, uid, ids, result, lower, upper, context=None):
>     res={}
>     flag = False
>     if float(result) < lower or float(result) > upper:
>         flag = True
>     res = {'warning': flag}
>     return {'value': res}
> ```

with **result** now being a **fields.char**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float fields will always have 0.0 as default. on_change will only be called whenever you change the value.

If you want to do any operation when value is "0" then you can use char field instead of float. You have to convert the value from string to float when your on_change is called and then you can do your operation further.

You can put your type cast code in try except and raise exception when except block is executed.

For example: try:

```
def on_change_float(self, cr, uid, ids, test1, context=None):
    val = float(test1)
    except Exception:
        raise osv.except_osv('Input Error ! ', 'Please enter numbers.')
    return {'value': {'test1': val}}
```

Comment: I was hoping I would'nt need to use a char field and cast it. So there's no other way?

Comment: I dont know why im bothering, what you're saying is accurate and rational, it works with char and casting. thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can cast char value only if it will have value in numbers. So you have to assume that user will not enter characters in that field.

Comment: yeah, that would be unpleasant, but i'd rather leave it that way since there is another adjacent field "result_text", and it's best to not let the user mix them up with the result=value