# Not getting a response from on_change event in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: python, xml, odoo, onchange

I am new to OpenERP and am inexperienced with programming in general. I am trying to get any response from an onchange event on a textfield. Someone else has reported that the code works, noting that the field must lose focus, so it might be an OS/browser/server related issue on my side.

I have tried many combinations of variables, as suggestions on forums, documentation and help sites such as stackoverflow differ.

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_form_custom">
      <field name="name">CRM - Leads Calendar.inherit</field> 
      <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" /> 
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="partner_name" on_change="testchange(contact_name)" /> <!-- Note: position="replace" works, have tried partner_name, context and combinations here. -->
        <!-- <field name="contact_name" /> -->
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Controller:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv # import crm/leads/view as well?

class modcontroller(osv.osv):
    """Attempting to change contact_name onchange partner_name (Company Name).
    """
    _inherit = "crm.lead"
    _columns = {
        'contact_name': fields.char('Contact Name', size=64, readonly=False),
        'partner_name': fields.char("Customer Name", size=64, help='Got your nose!', select=1, readonly=False),
                }
    _defaults = {
                 }

    def testchange(self, cr, uid, ids, contact_name): #partner_name, context=None
#         return {'warning': {'title': 'test', 'message': 'hello world'}}
#         raise Exception("Are you still there?")
        return {'value': {'contact_name': 'testing'}}


modcontroller()
```

As you can see I tried both raising an exception and showing a warning dialog, neither worked. It did detect a syntax error.

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
OpenERP 7.0 latest stable release including postgresql.
Browsers tried: Chrome and Firefox. Without NoScript.

As a side-note: I tried OpenERP on Ubuntu 12.04 VM with OpenERP nightly first but I ran into 100% CPU load issues which near-froze the OS (0.5 frames per second mouse movement).

Exerpt of related pages:
[Onchange function in Openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256227/onchange-function-in-openerp)
https://www.openerp.com/files/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf (see page 6, dynamic views)
http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic34853.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inheriting view `crm.crm_case_form_view_leads`, you have to specify which field in the view you have to inherit using the attribute `position = replace/after/before` attribute. Looking at your code, I think you are trying to add an `on_change` event to the field `partner_name` in CRM. This can be achieved by:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_form_custom">
  <field name="name">CRM - Leads Calendar.inherit</field> 
  <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" /> 
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_name']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="on_change">testchange(partner_name)</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Since the fields `partner_name` and `contact_name` are already present in the model `crm.lead`, you dont have to inherit the model `crm.lead` again and add those fields. So you can ommit the

```
_columns = {
    'contact_name': fields.char('Contact Name', size=64, readonly=False),
    'partner_name': fields.char("Customer Name", size=64, help='Got your nose!', select=1, readonly=False),
            }
```

part of your python file.